# react firebase add new document to collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to remove every value-field from the document "view-count" in the "server-details" collection in react with firebase. Currently I am deleting the document with deleteDoc() but I can't figure out how to create the document again. Here is my code:

```js
    const resetViewCounter = async () => {

        const valueDoc = doc(database, "server-details", "view-count");
        await deleteDoc(valueDoc);
        await addDoc(valueDoc);

        // window.location.reload(false); // temporarily
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `setDoc(valueDoc.ref, {})`.

But I'd recommend actually deleting the specific fields, with `FieldValue.delete` as shown in the documentation on [deleting fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not knowing the individual object object literals for every value field because I am having a bunch of ip's together with the timestamp as values. For example: "192.168": "Monday..." What would you recommend then?

Comment: And when I am using `setDoc(valueDoc.ref, {})` I get the following error: `index.esm2017.js:16396 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined`

Comment: 1) I'd still recommend explicitly deleting the fields by name, for example by looping over the fields in your document snapshot and generating a delete instruction for each of them. 2) I expected you to stuff whatever remaining fields you want inside that `{}`. Worst case, just add a singly dummy field in there or (my usual one) a `lastUpdated: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8_9)/